# Micali-Vazirani algorithm implementation in python library

Tags: library, python, software-development

I'm looking for a library that implements the Micali-Vazirani algorithm (1980) for maximum cardinality matching in general graphs. I find multiple implementations of the slightly older blossom algorithm (1961), yet this preforms *significantly* worse.

I see a couple implementations on github ([1](https://github.com/AlexanderSoloviev/mv-matching/blob/master/matching/matching.py), [2](https://github.com/mh3166/Extended_MV_algorithm/blob/master/mv_algorithm_fast_test.py)), but none that are relatively bug-free or part of a package.

Comment: did you manage to find a good implementation eventually?

Comment: @FabianBosler - no. I ended up adapting the ones above I believe

Comment: you wouldn't happen to have the code?